# awk: How to add a constant to a number every Nth line out of M lines in place?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, awk, sed

I am currently having trouble editting a file using bash script. It is a file which contains the Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) of a series of atoms at hundreds of timestamps. For a system consisting of 3 atoms, it looks like below:

```
t=1 x y z  
O 1.2 1.5 0.8  
H 0.4 2.3 1.3  
H 1.3 2.5 1.1  
t=2 x y z  
O 1.3 1.6 0.9  
H 0.3 2.5 1.2  
H 1.1 2.3 0.9  
t=3 x y z   
O 1.2 1.8 1.0  
H 0.5 2.2 1.1  
H 1.5 2.1 0.8  
t=4 x y z  
...
```

Now I want to add a constant 10 to the z-coordinate in every 3rd line out of 4 lines. Does anyone has any idea how to solve this?

I have tried with awk. However, it can only ouput the modified lines. It is important to mention that I want to MODIFY the original file in place, not just output the modified lines.

```
awk '{ if ((NR - 3) % 4 == 0) {$4=$4+10; print}}' file > outputfile
```

The expected output is as below:

```
t=1 x y z  
O 1.2 1.5 0.8  
H 0.4 2.3 11.3  
H 1.3 2.5 1.1  
t=2 x y z   
O 1.3 1.6 0.9  
H 0.3 2.5 11.2  
H 1.1 2.3 0.9  
t=3 x y z  
O 1.2 1.8 1.0  
H 0.5 2.2 11.1  
H 1.5 2.1 0.8  
t=4 x y z   
...
```

Now I am only getting:

```
H 0.4 2.3 11.3  
H 0.3 2.5 11.2  
H 0.5 2.2 11.1  
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want (notice the print outside the braces)

```
cp file file.ORI
awk '{ if ((NR - 3) % 4 == 0) {$4+=10} print}' file > temp && \
mv temp file
```

save `file.ORI` just in case...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Perl:

```
perl -i -lape 'if ($. % 4 == 3) { $F[3] += 10; $_ = "@F" }' file
```

The `-i` switch makes it (appear to) work in place. Use `-i.bak` to produce `file.bak` containing the original data.

`$.` stores the current line number; `$. % 4 == 3` selects the 3rd line from every group of 4 lines. `$F[3] += 10` increments the 4th field of the line by 10.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify your awk code a bit:

```sh
awk '{ if(NR%4==3) $4=$4+10; print }' file > outputfile
```

After file `outputfile` is generated, you can just just run `mv outputfile file` if you need the original file to be replaced.

Comment: `NR%4==3{$4+=10}1` would be more awkish

Comment: totally agree @oguzismail :D

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to count records and run the potential for a miscount causing the increment to the wrong line, you can key off of the records that have an `'='` sign in them and then use a counter from there, e.g.

```
awk '/=/{n=0} n==2{$4+=10} {n++}1' file
```

**Explanation**

There are three rules used in the `awk` expression:

- `/=/{n=0}` if the line contains `'='` set counter zero;
- `n==2{$4+=10}` couter equals `2` increment 4th field by `10`;
- `{n++}` increment counter.

The `1` at the end is the default for print record.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '/=/{n=0} n==2{$4+=10} {n++}1' file
t=1 x y z
O 1.2 1.5 0.8
H 0.4 2.3 11.3
H 1.3 2.5 1.1
t=2 x y z
O 1.3 1.6 0.9
H 0.3 2.5 11.2
H 1.1 2.3 0.9
t=3 x y z
O 1.2 1.8 1.0
H 0.5 2.2 11.1
H 1.5 2.1 0.8
t=4 x y z
```

You can redirect to a new file and then overwrite the original as needed.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
l=0 #line counter
while read -r h x y z; do # read a line and store each field in variables h x y z
  l=$((l+1)) # increment line counter
  if [ $l -eq 4 ]; then
    # fourth line including header = 3rd line of data
    z="$(echo "scale=1;$z+10" | bc)" # add 10 to Z
    l=0 # reset line counter for next data block
  fi
  echo "$h $x $y $z" # output the line
done <file # the whole loop reads from file
```

Comment: Sorry I am too stupid to comprehend this script. I cannot find where is the code for  'every 3rd line'...

Comment: I added comments

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, bash and bc):

```
sed -i '3~4{s/\S\+/$(echo "&+10"|bc -l)/4;s/.*/echo "&"/e}' file
```

Using sed's modulus command, from line 3 add 10 to the 4th field using `bc` every 4 lines.